# Binding & CustomViewSource applying together in a datagrid wpf

Tags: wpf

I have a CustomViewSource for grouping data in datagrid. XAML code is as:

```
 <local:DataCollection x:Key="dataCollection" />
     <CollectionViewSource x:Name="abc"
                           x:Key="cvs"
                           Source="{StaticResource dataCollection}" 
                           Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter">
          <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
               <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="CLAIM_ENCOUNTER" />
               <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="ACTIVITY" />
               <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="OBSERVATION" />
          </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
      </CollectionViewSource>
 </local:DataCollection>
```

Here dataCollection is the data I am populating in code behind.

```
 DataCollection _tasks = (DataCollection)this.Resources["dataCollection"];
 foreach (DataRow item in DtAllData.Rows)
 {
      _tasks.Add(new GroupData()
      {
          CLAIM_ENCOUNTER = item["CLAIM_ENCOUNTER"].ToString(),
          CLAIM_ID = item["Claim_Id"].ToString(),
          ...
      }
 }
```

Its populated using class. Datagrid is populating as :

```
<DataGrid 
    x:Name="GridAll"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.RowSpan="2"
    BorderBrush="Transparent"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
    CanUserAddRows="False"
    CanUserDeleteRows="False"
    CanUserReorderColumns="False"
    CanUserResizeColumns="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}"
    HeadersVisibility="Column"
    HorizontalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
    VerticalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    Margin="3">
</DataGrid>
```

My problem is, inside this datagrid, i want one image to display by binding. Its binding path I set as :

```
Binding="{Binding Path=CLAIM_ID,
   UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
   RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
      AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},AncestorLevel=1},
   Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Please help me...... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to bind to a property of your UserControl.

1) ensure your UserControl itself has a name (usually at the top of your xaml class):

```
<UserControl x:Class="myNameSpace.MyUserControl"
             x:Name="MyUserCtrl1"
             ...
```

2) set binding

```
<Image Source="{Binding ElementName=MyUserCtrl1, Path=ClaimImage}" .. />
```

Requirements:

- UserControl.DataContext created
- ClaimImage is an Image source in your UserCntrol, e.g an `Uri` (and not a string like CLAIM_ID)

  `ClaimImage = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/claimImage.png");`

Comment: I added name for UserControl.
  x:Name="ViewData"
But in the case of image, i already place the image. I want set a trigger with the Claim_id value as if Claim_id is null, image must collapse. How to code it??

Comment: I added name for UserControl